# UILocalNotification alertBody and action not localized

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, uilocalnotification

I'm currently trying to schedule local notifications with a localized message and action. But, even I change the iPhone language, the next notification is still in the previous language :(

The following code is used to schedule local notif and is called once user is registered (didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:) or when the language (stored in NSUserDefault) has changed :

```
- (void)scheduleNotifForDate:(NSDate*)date andHour:(NSString*)hour andMessage:(NSString*)keyMessageLocalized repeatedDayly:(BOOL)repeated withAction:(NSString*)keyActionLocalized andUserInfos:(NSDictionary*)userInfos {
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

NSString* dateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date], hour];

NSDateFormatter *dateTimeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateTimeFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
if (cls != nil) {
    UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
    notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notif.fireDate = [dateTimeFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
    notif.alertBody = NSLocalizedString(keyMessageLocalized, nil);
    notif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(keyActionLocalized, nil);
    notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notif.repeatInterval = repeated ? NSCalendarUnitDay : NSCalendarUnitWeekday;
    notif.userInfo = userInfos;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
}
```

}

Did I miss something to have a localized message ?
I have a workaround which cancel the local notif and reschedule it with the same parameters and, once rescheduled, it works perfectly. But it means if the user does not open the app after changing the language, it will still be displayed in the previous language.

Thanks & Regards,
Sebastien.

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
notif.alertTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"location", @"location");
notif.alertBody = NSLocalizedString(@"location", @"location");
```

Comment: Could you please further explain? Is there a native location.strings somewhere?